# Ignore case sensitive in FluentValidation

Tags: c#, .net, fluentvalidation

Anyone have any ideas to ignore case in FluentValidation

Example
`RuleFor(x => x.Gender).Ignorecase();`
so user would able to enter `F` or `f`.

Answer (score 1):

The [Equal Validator](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/built-in-validators.html#equal-validator) supports this:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Gender).Equal("f", StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

can you do the following?

```
RuleFor(x.ToLower() => x.Gender.ToLower());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think built-in Regex validation will do the work:
https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/wiki/c.-Built-In-Validators#regular-expression-validator

Somethink like:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Gender).Matches("^[FfMm]{1}$");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by create an Extension method

```
public static bool EqualsIgnoreCase(this string from, string to)
 { 
   return string.Equals(from, to, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase); 
 }
```

then use it like bellow:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Gender.EqualsIgnoreCase("f"))
```